# How to create Table Function that returns row for each line of a string, and returns empty table if string is null or empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, table-functions

Although I found answers for the individual parts of this question, I am posting this because I did not find an answer that consolidated these into one solution.  Thought I would post my solution in case anyone else had the same question.

This is my first post and I am new to SQL-Server, so any comments or recommendations greatly appreciated.

The function below returns

1) A table that contains a row for each line of a string,

2) If string is empty or null, returns an empty table, and

3) If delimiter is null or empty returns single row table containing string.

I made it generic, so I could use it to brake up CSV into rows.

USAGE

@Delimiter: Value used to determine where to break up string for placement in table rows

@Remove_Delimiters: Determines whether @Delimiter kept in strings placed in table rows

@String: String to be split up and placed into table rows.

TO SPLIT STRING INTO LINES: Set @Delimiter CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

TO SPLIT STRING INTO CSV Values: Set @Delimiter ','

NOTE: Another function required to remove extra white space

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[QaAuto_STRING_2TABLE]
(
    @Remove_Delimiters BIT
    , @Delimiter NVARCHAR(4000)
    , @String NVARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS @Table TABLE
(
    Row INT NOT NULL
    , Value NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT (@String IS NULL OR @String = '')
    BEGIN
        WITH Cte AS
        (
            SELECT StartIndex = 0, EndIndex = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT EndIndex ,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, EndIndex) + LEN(@Delimiter)
            FROM Cte WHERE EndIndex > StartIndex
        )   
        INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 
            Row  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) 
            ,Value = 
                CASE
                    WHEN @Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '' THEN @String
                    ELSE SUBSTRING(@String, StartIndex, 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN EndIndex > LEN(@Delimiter) 
                            THEN EndIndex-StartIndex - (LEN(@Delimiter)*@Remove_Delimiters)
                            ELSE LEN(@String) - StartIndex + LEN(@Delimiter) 
                        END)
                END
        FROM Cte
        WHERE StartIndex > 0
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/961695 replace commas with newline separators

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you're trying to solve here - can you post the full original question with some examples?

Comment: Question updated with my solution.  Let me know what you think and if there are better solutions for this same task.